# What are necessary and sufficient conditions such that $X^2+Y^2$ is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

> Let $X,Y$ be $n\times n$ matrices such that $X^3=Y^3$ and $X^2Y=Y^2X$. What are necessary and sufficient conditions on $X$ and $Y$ such that $X^2+Y^2$ is invertible?

I believe $X=Y$ is a sufficient condition, but how does one find all the necessary and sufficient conditions?

I tried writing it out individually as $XXX=YYY$ etc, but just found jumbles of $X, Y, X^{-1}$, and $Y^{-1}$ which really don't help me much. The problem is that as far as I know there is no simple way to link $\det(A+B)$ to $\det A$ and $\det B$.

However, I am not looking for a full answer, but rather for hints... I already have the answer but am choosing not to look.

Comment: So, if $X$ is non-invertible, $2X^2$ is?

Comment: $X=Y$ is certainly not sufficient. Imagine a diagonal matrix with at least one zero on the diagonal.

Comment: choosing $X=Y=0$ shows that $X=Y$ is not sufficient

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To help you get started, note that $(X^2+Y^2)(X-Y) = X^3-Y^3+Y^2X-X^2Y = 0$. Mouseover the lines below if you need more details.

> So if $X^2+Y^2$ is invertible, then we must have $X-Y = (X^2+Y^2)^{-1}0 = 0$, i.e. $X = Y$.

.

> It is easy to show that if $X = Y$ and $X$ is invertible, then $X^2+Y^2 = 2X^2$ is invertible, and if $X = Y$ but $X$ is not invertible, then $X^2+Y^2 = 2X^2$ is not invertible.

.

> Therefore, $X^2+Y^2$ is invertible iff $X = Y$ and $X$ is invertible.